# ELK Watcher use array compare for nested buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-watcher

I am using ELK watcher for alerts version 2.2, i have my query output something like this

```
{
    "took": 549,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
    "total": 1040,
    "successful": 1040,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 468101,
"max_score": 0,
"hits": [ ]
 },
 "aggregations": {
   "2": {
     "buckets": [
     {
      "6": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
             {
               "1": {
               "value": 84.86304909560724
               },
             "key": "hostname",
             "doc_count": 10000
      }


         ]
 },
    "key_as_string": "2016-11-09T19:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1478718000000,
    "doc_count": 47855
}
```

in the condition of the watcher i want to compare if "value" is greataer than some threshold,

i tried using array_compare but it does not work for nested arrays like this one
it matches for fields upto sum_other_doc_count but does not go further.

if anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to something I am trying to figure out.  Assuming you're okay just comparing values in the first elements of the arrays/buckets, I've had luck using the syntax:

```
"condition": {
    "compare": {
        "ctx.payload.aggregations.2.buckets.0.6.buckets.1.value": {
            "gte": 80
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest naming your "aggs" to avoid the 'magic numbers' above (aside from the hard-coded '0' for the first element in bucket).